# Flux.switchIfEmpty - what if it doesn't switch when first Flux is completed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, functional-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the following scenario, there are two endpoints (let's call them A and B) which return some values, these I need to process and report to a third endpoint (let's call it C). Values which can't be combined/processed I need to report to the same third endpoint (C) at the very end.

I did this by creating a Flux from each endpoint A and B which I `combineLatest` and then when I process the combined values I post these results to endpoint C. If the values can't be processed I store them in a Map.

After some thought I decided to create a third Flux from this Map that I should process when the two endpoints stop returning values. When they stop, I complete each of the Fluxes A and B, which in turn should complete `flux1`. `combineLatest` ensures that I will still be polling either A or B when one of them completes.

I have a method where I create a Flux from the Map above. I am hoping this method will actually be called only when the first Flux completes. I try to do this by doing `switchIfEmpty`.

Here is some pseudocode below:

```java
var flux1 = Flux.combineLatest(fluxA, fluxB, Tuple<A,B>)
                .processRecords(Tuple<A,B>)
                .prepareDataToBeSent();

var flux2 = createFluxFromValuesInMap();

flux1.switchIfEmpty(flux2)
     .flatMap(sendResult)
     .subscribe();
```

The first part, of flux1 processing works. But flux2 never is processed. At first I thought it is because the Map in question is empty at the very beginning, since only when flux1 finishes processing all values it will have something in it. But then I see that this method where `flux2` is creates isn't even called.

Can that be because the `flux1` actually completes?

I am not sure how to do this with reactor otherwise?

UPDATE: After some testing, I guess if `flux1` completes, `flux2` will not start emitting. But, is there at all a way to chain fluxes if one of them completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *empty* flux is a stream that completes without emitting a single value.

Therefore, *switchIfEmpty* is triggered only when upstream flow has never emitted value.

What you want is [*flux1.concatWith(flux2)*](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatWith-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-), that starts `flux2` after `flux1` is completed, with or without having emitted elements.